# compare a postgres and db2 table

Tags: java, postgresql, db2

normally i would solve this with a simple union.  but this one has me.  i have a table replicated to two different database engines.  one copy in postgres, one copy on an AS/400 with DB2.

i need to come up with a routine that takes the postgres table, and compares the data in the fields of each record with the DB2 table and log the different records in a postgres table for reporting.

the current system follows this model

```
    load postgres data into recordset prs
for each record in prs {
  search for record in db2
  compare record
  if diff, log
}
```

this normally works.  the problem, seeing there are about 500,000 records it takes about 3 hours before it triggers a bug in our VPN that kills the connection.  and of course you have to start over and it will be quicker to redesign the routine than to fix the VPN bug.

i was thinking of a routine that brings the db2 data over in a temporary table and doing a union query then, but i run into security issues with creating and dropping the table.

the most realistic method i can think of is loading the db2 data as a recordset, then loading it into a hashmap with the key being the db id number, and then looping the postgres data but that could really slam my memory resources.  but its still more of a brute force technique.  is there a more elegant solution you guys can think of?

edit--
sorry, the table starts the year with 3.5 million records so the in memory solution becomes pretty impractical.  any ideas?

Comment: You don't list the version, but is the SQL command `DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE` available?  It doesn't look like you need `CREATE TABLE` authority to run it.  Table can't be shared between sessions (not even logged to the system schema), and goes away when the connection ends - which means that when you finish, you don't even have to manually clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

What I would try to do is to partition the primary keys into ranges making the size per job manageable (and under the time it takes to trigger your VPN bug).

Using those ranges open 2 recordsets, 1 for each table, iterating both comparing records as you go (kinda like merge sort but now for diffing between 2 sources). That should be faster than querying the other table to look for the record.

Comment: im experimenting right now with an idea.  im thinking of opening the 3.5 million records in memory as before, but have a hashmap of two fields.  the dbid and an md5 hash of the value of the other fields.  then when i open the postgres records, i can compare the hashes and only hit the 400 for the exceptions after that point.  or something like that.  im experimenting with how hard its going to hit the 400 to open the initial recordset.